# Schur's lemma for $k$-algebra from algebraic closed field $k$.

Tags: field-theory, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

Let $R$ be $k$-algebra, where $k$ is algebraic closed field. Let $E$ be simple $R$-module. Then, how can I show that $End_{R}(E) \cong k$ ?

I know that Schur's Lemma, stating that "For two simple module $E, F$, Every nonzero homomorphism of $E$ into $F$ is an isomorphism, and $End_{R}(E)$ is a division ring" would be helpful, but don't know how to use this.

Comment: I don't think you can unless $E$ is assumed to be finite dimensional. If it is, then use that any endomorphism will have an eigenvector.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft 
  Thank you. So you mean that for any $\sigma \in End_{R}(E)$, $\sigma$ has eigenvector in $E$, but submodule generated by this eigenvector must be $E$ itself, from simplicity of $E$. Therefore, any two endomorphism sharing eigenvector must equal. Thus, I can get a map from endomorphism to its eigenvalue, and this map is injective since two endomorphism having the same eigenvalue are equal. And since $k$ is algebraically closed, this eigenvalue are must in $k$, so that it is surjective. Thus, $End_{R}(E) \cong k$.
Am I right?

Comment: Simpler: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $\sigma - \lambda I$ has non-trivial kernel.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh I got it. Yes. take map from $\sigma$ to such $\lambda$. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, your idea of looking at the submodule generated by an eigenvector is a good one in general and more or less formed the starting point for the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06975 that I wrote with V. Mazorchuk.